# Does the Stack Exchange Android app contain any hidden charges?

Tags: support, android-app, sign-up

I mean is this app absolutely free or will I have to pay later for any questions that I ask now?

Comment: Pretty sure this will be free for as long as the Stack Exchange sites are (for the foreseeable future).

Comment: Important question to give space for.

Answer (score 8):

It's 100% free. We don't charge anyone for access to our sites and certainly not to ask or answer questions.